# adding slide effect in react bootstrap accordion component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

**what is happening**

I am trying to add the react bootstrap accordion component into the react bootstrap Modal component. it means, rendering Modal first and then inside that, trying to render the accordion component.

below is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import "./de.css";

import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";

import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

export default class Dev1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.toggleDetails= this.toggleDetails.bind(this);
    this.toggleBats = this.toggleBats.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      bates: false,
      details: false
    };
  }

  toggleDetails(){
    const currentState = this.state.details;
    this.setState({ details: !currentState }); 
  }
  toggleBats(){
    const currentStateBates = this.state.bates;
    this.setState({ batches: !currentStateBates }); 
  }


  render() {
    return <div>

     <Nav.Link className="viewdetails" onClick={() => this.toggleDetails()}>View Details</Nav.Link>
     
<section>
       <Modal
        show={this.state.details}
        onHide={this.toggleDetails}
        dialogClassName="modal-90w"
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={true}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Welcome </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
        <div>
        <Accordion>
  <Card className="accordian">
    <Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
        Click me!
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    </Card.Header>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
        Click me!
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    </Card.Header>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
</Accordion>
  </div>

        </Modal.Body>
        
        
        </Modal>

       </section>


    </div>;
  }
}
```

**what is the issue**

The behavior of the accordion component is not like sliding nut instead it is hide and show. in the [react bootstrap accordion basic example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/) , sliding is happening but in above code it is not. not able to get what is the issue. please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important part of what makes it slide is the `transition` implementation

```
.collapsing {
    transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

It may have been overridden by one of your custom style sheets. It is hard to root out the problem in dev tools because that `class` I've mentioned is actually removed & added on the actual transition process (in a matter of less than 1 second) - so could either manually add that style to the DOM just to review it on dev tools or you would have to search your custom stylesheets for any rules that may have tampered with that.

You find here https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-leakey-uqgy8?file=/src/App.js:1854-1896 a working example